# 403 Validando tokens y sesiones (SIMPLEJWT, Django REST)

Tags: django, djangorestframework, jwt

Estoy realizando un API Rest con Django REST Framework y autenticación, sin embargo cuando estoy probando la funcionalidad mediante un cliente REST, la vista que tengo protegida mediante el permiso isAuthenticated me está generando un problema el cual es que así pase el Token (Bearer Token, en postman/insomnia) este está arrojando un Forbidden 403 65 sin importar que esté utilizando el método get o post. Cabe aclarar que el login y el refresh token son obtenidos de la url /login/ del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo User:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
import uuid


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    # Create a user with email and password

    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        # Create a superuser with email and password
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('email', max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField('password', max_length=256)
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=200)
    can_create_users = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        some_salt = 'V2lzaCBvbiBhbiBFeWVsYXNo'
        self.password = make_password(self.password, some_salt)
        super().save()

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Serializador de User:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from certificationsApp.models.user import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'password', 'name', 'can_create_users']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return user

    def update(self, validated_data):
        updated_data = super().update(validated_data)
        updated_data.save()
        return user

    def delete(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.get(id=validated_data['id'])
        user.delete()
        return user

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        user = User.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        return {
            'id': user.id,
            'email': user.email,
            'name': user.name,
            'can_create_users': user.can_create_users
        }
```

View Users (aún no he implementado bien la funcionalidad de post, ya que tengo el problema de autenticación..):

```
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.backends import TokenBackend
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from certificationsApp.models.user import User
from certificationsApp.serializers.UserSerializer import UserSerializer


class Users(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')[7:]
        #token_backend = TokenBackend(algorithm=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['ALGORITHM'])
        #valid_data = token_backend.decode(token, verify=False)
        # validate if user can create users
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView
from certificationsApp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
    path('users/', views.Users.as_view()),
    path('users/<str:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
]
```

settings del proyecto:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'certificationsApp',
]

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=20),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATIONS_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'certificationsApp.User'
```

De antemano, muchas gracias!.